# Forward Declaration of a typedef to a Primitive Type

Tags: c++, include, typedef, primitive, forward-declaration

Say that in my file I want to do:

```
typedef vector<foo> foos
```

If `foo` is a class in another file I can forward declare that: `class foo`. But if `foo` is itself a `typedef` of a primitive, I don't know how to handle that. For example say in another file I have done:

```
typedef int foo
```

Are my only choices to `#include` the file `foo` is `typedef`'d in, or to do `typedef vector<int> foos`? For readability and association I'd prefer to avoid both of these options. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Make a types header that just has the typedefs and include them in both files?

Comment: @NathanOliver T.T I don't want to `#include <vector>` in my types definition file. Please don't make me do it. It'll be included everywhere.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that.  I suggesting you put `typedef int foo` in a header file and then include it in the files you want to use `foo` in.

Comment: you could make yourself a wrapper class around `foo` when it is a primitive type, so you could forward it.

Comment: @NathanOliver `foo` is really a `typedef` for a 32-bit integer, so it's used literally everywhere... You know how we have to do those `typedef`s in C++ cause who knows what `int` really means >:|

Comment: I still don't see the problem.  You can use `int32_t` if you want a 32 bit `int` or you could but `typedef int32_t my_int` in a header file and include that in all files where you need `my_int`.  It's not going to add any overhead and now you only have one place you need to change anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right... but the file that defines the `foo` that we're supposed to use was written by someone else and there's all manor of junk in there I didn't want to `#include`. Even saying that I know that the right solution is to break that junk out of the integer `typedef`'ing file and create another header for it. I can do that, but that is going to incur a significant amount of work. re-`#including` that new header where it's needed. I'm asking this question to see if there is a way around that. It sounds like you're telling me that there isn't :(

Comment: I see.  Hopefully someone will know of a way then.  AFAIK there isn't C++ has a lot of little tricks in it so it wouldn't surprise me if there was something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that you can do the same `typedef` more than once, in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) only, not in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

> Once declared, a typedef-name may only be redeclared to refer to the same type again <sup>[[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)]</sup>

As such, just as you would use `class foo` to forward declare `foo` if it was a type you may also do:

```
typedef int foo
```

Then your `typedef vector<foo> foos` will compile fine. This won't violate the principle of [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) because the compiler will enforce that all `typedef`s match. If you decide to change the type though it will require you to also go edit all the files that it was also defined in to match.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler must know size of allocated type to build the code.

Solution is to use semantics of Handles, for example.

They are usually void*.

You may to cast 'em to numbers when size OK.

```
typedef void* foohandle;

reinterpret_cast<foohandle>(foo);

reinterpret_cast<int32_t>(foo handle);
```

But better is to use handles as pointers of concrete type.